# Ordering doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I'm defining @courses variable in my Course#index method in several ways:

```
  def index
    @courses = Course.order("title")                                                                                           
    # @courses = Course.all
    # @courses = Course.paginate(page: params[:page] )
    # @courses = Course.order("subject_id").order("student_level_id")
  end
```

I have a partial view to display the set: `_course.html.slim`:

```
li
  => link_to(course.title.capitalize, course)
```

The problem is, while displaying the Courses set, the order doesn't change regardless which way I define my `@courses`. Although in `rails console` there is a difference in order.

**UPDATE**

This is a courses/index.html.slim, it is a basic example from Hartl's tutorial.

```
 ul.users
  = render @courses
```

By the way, in another place (on homepage /static_pages/home.html.slim), this same code snippet results in other ordering.

So, I am wondering, maybe it is some kind of caching problem....

What might be the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am downvoting your question because you did not provide the relevant snipped of your code, where you actually use `@courses`

Comment: I added index.html.slim contents for Course view.

Comment: Look at your rails server output to see what query it's doing each time you load the page.  For the example you have above, it should be something like `SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" ORDER BY title`

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

There were two separate `@courses` instances defined, each in two different controllers, so because of this I got discrepancies in answers, because only one instance was ordered.

To stay DRY, I moved ordering from a controllers

```
@courses = Course.order("subject_id").order("student_level_id")
```

to Course model:

`default_scope order: "courses.subject_id, courses.student_level_id"`

and changed all definitions in my controllers to a simple `Course.all`.

Also, I believe I found answer to this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583858/default-scope-ordering-based-on-associated-models-attributes

Thank you very much for help!